# How to exclude elements while exporting documents?

Tags: marklogic

I have thousands of XML documents stored in MarkLogic. How can I exclude elements `instructorName` and `studentName` in `$uris` then save to files?

This code saves every element into files. I don't want to include elements "instructorName" and "studentName" to be saved into xml files.

```
let $uris :=
  cts:uris(
    (),
    ("descending"),
    cts:and-query((
        cts:collection-query(("/courses")),
        cts:element-value-query(
          xs:QName("note"), "COGNITIVE   SCIENCE", "case-insensitive")
    ))
  )
for $uri in $uris
let $doc := fn:doc($uri)
let $courseID := fn:data($doc//meta:courseid)
return xdmp:save(fn:concat("/output/",$courseID,".xml"), $doc)
```

Thanks in advance
Thichxai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using cts:uris() followed by fn:doc(), you should just use cts:search() to get the documents matching the query in one pass:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search

Beyond that, I'm not entirely sure which of two goals you're trying to accomplish.

If you want to extract elements other than those elements, use XPath.  The specific XPath will depend on the structure of your document, but assuming these are top-level child elements, the approach would be similar to:

```
for $doc in cts:search(...)
let $root := $doc/*
let $hide := $root/(instructorName|studentName)
let $keep := ($root/node() except $hide)
let $newDoc := document-node{element {node-name($root)} {$keep}}
return xdmp:save(..., $newDoc)
```

If you want to hide the documents that have those elements, try changing your query to something like:

```
cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query("/courses"),
    cts:not-query(
        cts:element-query(
            (xs:QName("instructorName"), xs:QName("studentName")),
            cts:true-query()
            ))
    ))
```

For more, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:not-query

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks for answering.  What I try to accomplish is

Comment: Thanks for answering question.  I try this and it works.
   let $copymeta := <meta:Metadata> 
                       {$doc//meta:Metadata/*[(fn:local-name() != "instructorname")]}
                </meta:Metadata> 
   
                                          
   let $newdoc := <record>
                       
                        { $copymeta }
                           
                 </record>

Answer (score 1):

The forthcoming MarkLogic 9 has element-level security, which I think would solve this problem.
[This article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/marklogic-9-security-harry-bakken?articleId=8353400876426261965) describes how it works.

You'd want to create a user that has read-privileges for the documents as a whole, but not for the instructorName/studentName XPaths. Then run [MLCP](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) as that user to dump the documents to files.